# Function that takes a 2D array and returns a tuple of the array's columns?

Tags: arrays, tuples, julia

How can I convert a 2D array (`n`-by-`m`) into an tuple of `m` vectors of length `n` that correspond to the columns of the array? In other words, I want a function `f` such that

```
julia> f([1 2 3; 4 5 6])
([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
```

Does Julia provide such a function? If not, how can I write one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no built-in Julia function that does what you want, i.e.

- take a two-dimensional array (`Array{T,2}`),
- return a tuple of vectors `(Array{T,1},Array{T,1},...)`) corresponding to the array's columns.

However, you can write one yourself easily enough by using a combination of

- a list comprehension,
- the `...` operator,
- the `size` function,
- the `tuple` function.

#### Putting it all together

```
function f{T<:Any}(A::Array{T,2})
    return tuple([A[:,c] for c in 1:size(A,2)]...)
end
```

#### Example

```
julia> A = rand(4,5)
4x5 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.21149   0.841894  0.275182   0.33981   0.0142366
 0.88409   0.718435  0.368415   0.521676  0.527016 
 0.482613  0.211109  0.394439   0.141225  0.071393 
 0.4477    0.330136  0.0303556  0.610213  0.699511 

julia> tup = f(A)
([0.21149,0.88409,0.482613,0.4477],[0.841894,0.718435,0.211109,0.330136],[0.275182,0.368415,0.394439,0.0303556],[0.33981,0.521676,0.141225,0.610213],[0.0142366,0.527016,0.071393,0.699511])

julia> typeof(tup)
(Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1})
```